# Double counting volume of revolution

Tags: calculus

I want to understand why is there no double-counting when using the volume of revolution formula on a circle. Say we want to find the volume of revolution in the first and second quadrants about the $y$ axis. Say the equation of the circle is $x^2+y^2=R^2$. Using the volume of revolution formula, we get
$$\int_{-R}^{R}\pi (R^2-x^2)dx=\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3$$
which is correct. However, aren't we rotating around the $y$ axis basically twice, as we are doing it once with the quarter circle from $x=0$ to $x=R$ and then again with the quarter circle from $x=-R$ to $x=0$?
There is some error with this logic that I can't find. Can someone please explain to me why the formula holds even though we are apparently doing the operation twice?

EDIT: I just had a thought. Is it because $x^2+y^2=R^2$ is not a function (as it fails the vertical line test)?

Comment: By the way, aren't you rotating around the $x$ axis when you use the formula $V=\pi\int y^2 dx$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{x=-R}^R \pi (R^2 - x^2) \, dx = \pi \left[R^2 x - \frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{x=-R}^R = \pi \left(R^3 - \frac{R^3}{3} - \left(-R^3 - \frac{(-R)^3}{3}\right)\right) = \frac{\color{red}{4}}{3}\pi R^3.$$

---

Now that the original question was edited to correct the arithmetic error, the follow-up answer is this:

There is no double counting because the integral is being calculated with respect to $x$, not $y$.  Therefore, the axis of revolution is the $x$-axis, not the $y$-axis, and the differential volume for a representative slice corresponds to a disk of thickness $dx$, and radius equal to the distance from the point $(x,0)$ to $(x, \sqrt{R^2 - x^2})$, i.e. $\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$.  This gives the full sphere volume as I have shown above.

If you want to calculate the volume of the **hemisphere** for a volume of revolution above the $x$-axis by rotating about the $y$-axis, then you would write the integral as follows:

$$\int_{y=0}^R \pi (R^2 - y^2) \, dy.$$  For a given $y \in [0,R]$, the differential volume element is a disk of thickness $dy$, with radius equal to the distance from $(0,y)$ to $(\sqrt{R^2 - y^2}, y)$.

Comment: Is there any reason that you wrote $x=-R$ as the lower limit for the integral rather than just $-R$?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent It's just my personal preference; a habit, if you will.  Some people find it redundant, but I find it convenient for keeping track of variables when writing multiple iterated integrals; e.g., $$\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=x}^{2-x} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx.$$  But the point is, the integral in question actually equals $\frac{4}{3} \pi R^3$--it counts the full volume of the sphere.

Comment: @heropup thank you for the answer. This does not address my question. My question is why is there no double counting of the full volume of the sphere, as aren't we basically rotating twice (coming from the rotation of the part that is $0<x<R$ which is the same volume as $-R<x<0$?

Comment: @MathsWizzard No.  See my edited answer.